# deduction of some hour and minute from NOW() in php

Tags: php

how can I subtract some hour and minute form the current datetime in php?

example:
current date: 2016-11-22 14:15:50
I need to deduce 1 hr & 25 minute from this ..

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$time = time()-1*60*60-25*60;
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($time));
```

Comment: Wrong order of parameters there.

Answer (score 1):

Using simply `strtotime`

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("-1 hour -25 minutes"));
```

Using `DateTime` class

```
$date = new DateTime("-1 hour -25 minutes");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code might help you :

```
$newTime = strtotime('-15 minutes'); // as per your question it should be 85
echo 'Time: '.date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $newTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution: with PHP `DateTime`

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-11-22 14:15:50');
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P0Y0M0DT1H25M0S'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

**P** is period & **T** is Time.And you know: `Y= Year, M= Month, H= Hour, M= Minutes, and S= Second`.Just put your required time before these.You can blank `DateTime()` to get current time.

**[WORKING DEMO](http://phpio.net/s/16kp)**

Comment: I'm using datatable to show report .. so I need to do this in the following line :
$data_array[$i][$j++] = $row['rcvTime'];
how to do this?

Comment: `$rcvTime = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); $data_array[$i][$j++] = $row['rcvTime'];`  try this :/

Comment: nop.. I need to do this deduction procedure inside datatable ...